# Creative sdk Editing screen stays at portrait mode in Phones

Tags: android, adobe, aviary, adobecreativesdk

I am using **adobe creative sdk** in my **android** app. Its working great one issue I'm facing is that I am trying to **edit an image in landscape mode** in **phone** its not working the Edit screen sticks to Portrait mode in phone, even when I rotate my phone. But **its working fine in Tablets**.

Is there any extras do I have to pass to rotate the screen in phones. Or **does it allows image editing in landscape mode in phones**. I am stuck here. Please can anybody help me to solve this.

I am calling the intent as follows

```
Intent imageEditorIntent = new AdobeImageIntent.Builder(this)
                    .setData(Uri.parse(imgPath))
                    .withToolList(mTools)
                    .withOutput(file)
                    .build();

            startActivityForResult(imageEditorIntent, 200);
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine. The Image Editor doesn't currently support landscape mode on phones.